# Can anyone compile ffmpeg under windows for me?

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg

I'm just about getting insane with compiling ffmpeg under windows... It just won't work.
I need the avcodec.dll and avformat.dll inclusiv .lib and .h, maybe someone could  compile it for me and upload these files, so that I can use it at my own project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/